# using def to assign the value, but it does not work

Tags: python, function

I am really new in programming and have been trying to assign '1' to x if x is bigger than 8000 and to assign '2' to x if x is smaller than 1200...
It must be really simple, but I am not sure what I did wrong.. Please help me.

```
 def clas(x):
    if x>8000:
        x='1'
    elif x<1200:
        x= '2'
    else:
        x= '3'

print(clas(12))
```

Comment: can you check the indentation here and fix it please?

Comment: @Juho Lee Add return statement after **else** `return x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't return any value from the function so the new value of `x` is disappeared after function ends. If you want to use it after the function, you should return it:

```
def clas(x):
    if x>8000:
        x='1'
    elif x<1200:
        x= '2'
    else:
        x= '3'
    return x
print(clas(134))
```

> `2`